# Function with combinatory arguments

Tags: mathcad

I don't actuall know how to call this type of function.
So I want to make a function like this to work. I have a lot of variables Xi,j, so i don't want to write them all manually. How can i perform this?
[My implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyJpx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass matrix `X` in function

[image]

Ensure that the `ORIGIN = 1`